# Rails 3 Get the index position of a hash within array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing

I have a User model with attributes department and points. I have grouped the users by department and sorted each department by the number of points they contain, as shown below in my home/index view:

```
Accounting 158
Animal Science 98
Kinesiology 58
```

I simply want to get the index of each hash element in the array so I can do something like this:

```
1. Accounting 158
2. Animal Science 98
3. Kinesiology 58
```

This is the code in my home_controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController  
def index
@users = User.find(:all)
@dep_users = @users.group_by { |u| u.department}
end
```

And in my home/index view I have this code:

```
    <% @dep_users.sort.each do |department, users| %>
    <% @p = Array.new() %>

    <%= department %>
    <% for user in users %>
    <% @p << user.points %>
    <% end %>
    <%= @p.inject(:+) %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I have tried using each_with_index on @dep_users as such:

```
@dep_users.sort.each_with_index do |department, users, index|
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method 'each' for 0:FixNum when I do that
```

How could I get the index for each hash element in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it's a bad idea to move so much logic in your views. Better way is to define new method which will return sorted array `[[department1, points1], [department2, points2]]` in your model. Then call it from your controller to create an instance variable. And this variable in your view with code like this

```
<ol>
  <% @p.each do |item| %>
    <li><%= item[0] + '&nbsp;' + item[1] %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Let html puts numbers before each item of your list.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but had put the <ol> tag within the loop and it wasn't working. Whoops. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

for sorting a hash use Hash[hash_name.sort] cause it returns a hash. hash_name.sort returns an array.

```
1.9.2-p320 :077 > a
=> {:sameer=>40, :rohan=>25, :prasad=>26} 

> Hash[a.sort_by{|name, age| age}]
=> {:rohan=>25, :prasad=>26, :sameer=>40} 
> Hash[a.sort_by{|name, age| name}]
=> {:prasad=>26, :rohan=>25, :sameer=>40}
```